# How exactly do I use custom templates in Zim wiki?

Tags: templates, zim

When I go to `File > New Page`, the only available templates are the ones on the `wiki` folder. I created a separate folder to contain my custom templates but I can't figure out a way to select them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Help:Templates - Zim - a desktop wiki](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Templates.html)

> Zim uses templates when exporting pages. This way you can for example write your website in zim and export it to HTML using the layout and style definition of you choice.
>
> Templates are also used to initialize new pages.

To use more Wiki templates (while you make new notes), you add them to the Wiki folder.

Depending on where you installed zim: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zim Desktop Wiki\data\templates\wiki`